# What's this 1917 shell casing, more exactly?

Tags: world-war-one, artillery

I've been gifted this vase that is obviously made out of a large shell casing. It has 'MARZ 1917' stamped on the bottom, plus other less understandable markings: 'St', 'G', '36', 'HL 25'. I'm attaching a photo, of course.

The diameter of the largest part at the bottom is 90 mm, i don't have a caliper but by measuring the 'lip' i think the actual tube is 80-82 mm wide at the bottom and 76-77 mm at the top (it's been deformed by the beautification process).

It's not a matter of life and death, but it would be fun if someone could shed more light on what those markings say.

Thank you!

[image: Bottom with markings]

[image: Side view]

Comment: I've recently found one myself whilst digging a footing for an extension in West Molesley. Same details except mine is date Sept 1917. Looks like someone brought one back from the war and it got lost in the garden. Its taking pride of place on my shelf. link to dropbox file with pictures.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

What you have is a casing from a [77mm German field artillery piece](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/7.7_cm_FK_96_n.A.), possibly like this:
[image]
Some of the stamps:

- St: Strengthened case
- HL: Haniel Luege Düsseldorf (brass factory)
- 25: Inspection Mark

not sure yet on the G([may indicate](http://1914-1918.invisionzone.com/forums/index.php?/topic/28930-shell-cases/) maker *Geschossfabrik*), and 36 may be lot number. März 1917, of course, would be the date.

---

some sites to look:

- [Large calibre markings on cartridge cases](https://ator1149.home.xs4all.nl/wfm/ww1/ammunition2.html)
- [Great War Forum-German Shell Case Markings](http://1914-1918.invisionzone.com/forums/index.php?/topic/160019-german-shell-case-markings/)

Comment: That will lead to another evening of reading references for fun. Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

Just adding a little detail, it is MÄRZ 1917 (A with [umlaut](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diaeresis_(diacritic))), the two dots over the A are a part of the text and not an accident.